# mysql php implode row for links?

Tags: php, mysql, explode, implode

Not sure if there a way of doing this, but I can insert multiple categories into MYSQL, using :

```
GetSQLValueString(implode($_POST['r_category'],", "), "text"),
```

So then when I echo:

```
<?php echo $row_Recordset1['r_category']; ?>
```

It is fine, like this: **Cat 1, Cat 2, Cat 3**

I am trying to find a way to link each category for easy navigation purposes!!

Like this:

```
<a href="/page/results.php?r_category=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['r_category']; ?>"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['r_category']; ?></a>
```

This works great for One Cat, but if I have multiple Cats, then it is one big link.... not what I want.

I need to use implode or explode, but not sure how ?  Thanks in advance!!!

This is what I would love:

Cat 1, Cat 2, Cat 3 (these are all separated links pulling from one row!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $row_Recordset1['r_category'] is the string "Cat 1, Cat 2, Cat 3", then you can explode that into an array like this:

```
$arr = explode(",", $row_Recordset1['r_category']);
```

then step through your array to create the links:

```
$links = array();
foreach ($arr as $value)
{
    $links[] = "<a href='/page/results.php?r_category=". trim($value) ."'>". trim($value) ."</a>";
}
$links_str = implode(", ", $links);
echo $links_str;
```

Comment: hmm.. great let me try. Does this work if i just have one Cat in the string, like Cat 1 only.. ?

Comment: EXCELLENT!! It worked, but now I am having problems echoing the result with a comma. If there is just one Cat, then their shouldn't be any comma, but if multiple, like Cat 1 and Cat 2, then there should be a comma separating them??

'echo "<a href='/page/results.php?r_category=". trim($value) ."'>". trim($value) ."</a>,  ";'

Comment: @eberswine see my edit for how to handle that properly.  We'll store each link in an array and re-implode.